# exe file generated by py2exe cannot do file operations

Tags: python, py2exe

Here's my situation. I used py2exe to generated some python codes to exe in Windows, everything works fine except for the file operations. The exe file cannot create open, read or close files while the python scripts works fine. 
It is a simple pyqt program that only includes some dialogs, string operations, and saving the results into a file.
Anyone has any clue about it? My python version is 3.4 and OS is Win7

Comment: are those files in uac protected area

Comment: You should be able to get an error and traceback from the py2exe exe which will reveal more.  Or if you can't work out how to do that, then try catching and printing the exception.  Just saying "cannot" is not very much detail.

Comment: Use `try...except error as e: print(e)` to print error. You can see the error traceback if you run your program from command prompt as it not closes immediately after the error occurred